# Rasterizing small polygons error

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I'm trying to *rasterize* a large dataset of polygons to a resolution of 0.5x0.5 degrees. While I don't have problems with large polygons I keep getting rasters full of "0" for the smallest ones. I found a really similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943820/problem-to-rasterize-small-polygons-with-rasterize-function) and apparently there is a solution using *"R"*. However I wonder how this problem could be solved in QGIS.